# CSS body for a single page in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How can we add CSS styling pages for only a single page in reactJS. I am trying to make a multi-page react application and I need to add a particular CSS styling background for a particular page only.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(110deg, #3f51b547 60%, #fafafacb 60%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(110deg, #3f51b547 60%, #fafafacb 60%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(110deg, #3f51b547 60%, #fafafacb 60%);
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #3f51b547 60%, #fafafacb 60%);
}
```

I am adding this in styles.css under that particular page directory and imported this file into a single page only. But still, I am getting this background for every page.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: Instead of styling the body tag style only the component tags of that particular page, like div or container

Comment: @AlfredoLipari Actually I need to have this style as my background in my page and over this background, I am trying to build different components.